# What's the article of Software Development Kit (SDK)?

Tags: loanword, software, english

Personally I'd say

> **das** Software Development Kit (SDK)

but everyone tells me different articles. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: I'm using "das" over "der" for some unknown reason.

Comment: Laut deinem Profileintrag bist du Österreicher, und daher vermute ich, dass deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist. Warum formulierst du deine Frage über einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache in einem Deutsch-Forum in einer Fremdsprache? Ich schätze mal, dass mehr als 95% aller Fragen hier von Menschen beantwortet werden, deren Muttersprache ebenfalls Deutsch ist. Wenn du in einer Fremdsprache fragst, erreichst du damit, dass auch die Antworten in einer Fremdsprache formuliert werden. Deutsche Muttersprachler unterhalten sich dann über die deutsche Sprache in einer Fremdsprache. Das ist nicht optimal.

Comment: Bitte bedenke, dass der Artikel von vier Parametern abhängt: 1. grammatisches Geschlecht (männlich/weiblich/sächlich), 2. vom grammatischen Fall (Genitiv, Dativ usw.), 3. von der Zahl (Einzahl/Mehrzahl) und 4. von der Bestimmtheit (bestimmt/unbestimmt). Von diesen vier Parametern ist nur das Geschlecht fix mit dem Substantiv verknüpft. Die drei anderen Parameter hängen von der Verwendung im Satz ab und haben keine feste Verbindung mit dem Wort selbst. Daher glaube, dass du vermutlich eher fragen wolltest: »Welches grammatische Geschlecht hat *SDK*?«

Answer (score 9):

The article of an abbreviation is defined by its "main" word. In SDK it's "kit". And according to [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kit) both *der* and *das* are correct.

Comment: I would **never** say *der Kit*, because there's *der Kit**t***, which means  *putty*. Remember *»Knight Rider«*? The car was named *K.I.T.T* in the German translation, too, which gave a good laugh anytime it was said (which was often.)

Answer (score 8):

Although according to Duden both "das" and "der" can be used I would always say "das Kit". First of all I used it all my life and secondly "der Kitt" is a kind of glue. I know that is not a scientific answer, but I am German, and believe me "der Kit" sounds strange to me in this acception.

Comment: It definitely does, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

Wie ich schon in einem Kommentar dargelegt habe, willst du vermutlich nicht den Artikel, sondern das grammatische Geschlecht wissen.

»*Software Development Kit*« ist ein zusammengesetzter Begriff. Für ihn gilt bezüglich des Geschlechts dieselben Regel, wie bei allen zusammensetzten Substantiven:

- Das grammatische Geschlecht eines zusammensetzten Substantivs ist das Geschlecht des letzen Bestandteils.

Der letzte Bestandteil deines Begriffs ist »*Kit*«, und dieses Wort kannst du in einem Wörterbuch nachschlagen.

- Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kit) gibt an, dass *Kit* wahlweise sächlich oder männlich ist.
- Auch [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kit) und ...
- [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kit) behaupten dasselbe.

Richtig ist also (im Nominativ, Singular, bestimmt):

- das Kit
- der Kit

Du darfst dir aussuchen, was davon du verwenden willst, nur solltest du innerhalb eines Dokuments nur eine der beiden Varianten verwenden (also nicht im selben Text abwechselnd die sächliche und die männliche Form verwenden).

---

Je nach Verwendung im Satz können aber auch diese Artikel korrekt sein:

- die Kits
- des Kits
- dem Kit
- den Kit
- ein Kit
- eines Kits
- einem Kit
- einen Kit